# How to do Inverse Tangent in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I need to know how to do an inverse tangent(Tan<sup>-1</sup>) in C# as there doesn't seem to be one under `Math`

Comment: Are you looking for [Math.Atan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Take note: Math.Atan returns `An angle, θ, measured in radians, such that -π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π/2.`

Answer (score 7):

You could just use

```
Math.ATan
```

This method takes one paremeter of type double, which represents a tangent and returns a double, which represents

> An angle, θ, measured in radians, such that -π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π/2.

For further documentation, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

That would be [`Math.Atan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Math.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Bear in mind that `Math.Atan` only calculates angles in radians between -π/2 and π/2. `Math.Atan2` is used for determining a quotient between two different doubles in order to find the value between -π and π in radians.